# Can anyone tell me why nothing is happen on the click of button?

Tags: android, listview

Not able to refresh the list..

I have two java file 
MainActivity.java
and CustomAdapter.java

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.dv.deletev;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    String name[]={"Ankit","Arora","Arun","yadav"};
    String no[]={"AnAnaAN","cccc","bbbbb","aaa"};
    static CustomAdapter obj;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        obj=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,name,no);

        lv.setAdapter(obj);

    }

    public static  CustomAdapter take()
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

and

> 

### CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.dv.deletev;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dv.deletev.*;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

String name[];
String no[];
    Context con;
    MainActivity a;
    public CustomAdapter(Context con,String a[],String b[])
    {
        super(con,R.layout.second,a);
        name=a;
        this.con=con;   
        no=b;
        }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater lv=(LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView=lv.inflate(R.layout.second, null);

    TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button  bt=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);      
        final List<String> arr1;
        final List<String> arr2;
        arr1=(List<String>) Arrays.asList(name);
        arr2=(List<String>) Arrays.asList(no);

        final ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>(arr1);
        final ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>(arr2);


    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        arr.remove(position);
        ar.remove(position);
        a.take().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
        tv1.setText(name[position]);
        tv2.setText(no[position]);

        return convertView;
    }







}
```

---

I don't know why on the click of button its not perform onclick function. I 
checked the code many times and its correct.

You can check output at: http://postimg.org/image/5fxs20wgp/
Any suggestions would be remarkable.. :)

Comment: Notify adapter after binding

Comment: what it means? pls expain

Comment: After binding adapter , use adpater.setnotiftyDatachange() method

Comment: there is no such method like you said

Comment: obj.notifyDataSetChanged(); now use this @priya

Comment: using obj.notifyDataSetChanged() gives error

Comment: use baseadapter instead of arrayadapter

Comment: they both are not same?

Comment: whats the differance between them?

Comment: no both are different BaseAdapter use for custom adapter and ArrayAdapter is for single adapter

Answer (score 0):

Please use ViewHolder pattern to improve your performance, 
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

I think onClick works, but you don`t see it, because you have to notify your list adapter, when removing an item.

```
CustomAdapter.this.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

To see that, onClick really works please add Log.e("1","1"); inside the onClick, I`m sure you are going to see the log, so actually onClick get`s called right now, you are forgetting to fresh the adapter.

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    Log.e("1","onClick");
    arr.remove(position);
    ar.remove(position);
    a.take().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: what does Log.e("1","onClick") do??

Comment: prints a log to your logcat, so you can see, is the method get`s called or not

Comment: okay, in this case apply the viewHolder patter first, because your code is not so clean, and I think we have an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

ok there are a couple of things that are wrong here.
1)notify the adapter
2)use view holder design pattern
3)since the button is inside list view the focus goes to list view, implement view holder and it will start working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    String name[]={"Ankit","Arora","Arun","yadav"};
    CustomAdapter obj;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,name,no);
        lv.setAdapter(obj);
        obj.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and change your adapter to

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    String name[];
    Context con;
    public CustomAdapter(Context con,String a[])
    {
        name=a;
        this.con=con;   
    }

static class Holder{
Button buton;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater lv=(LayoutInflater)       con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView=lv.inflate(R.layout.second, null);
    Holder holder = new Holder;
    if(convertView==null){
    Button  bt=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    convertView.setTag(holder);      
    }else{
      holder=convertView.getTag(holder)
    }   

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             Log.d("","inside click")
             todo embed logic here 
        }

    });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**After this line in your MainActivity.java**

> obj=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,name,no);
>
> lv.setAdapter(obj);

**You can write this**

> obj.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I hope its clear enough to understand and if not then let me know

Comment: this causes Exception... My application crashed

Comment: ya you can use Base adapter instead of Arrayadapter

Comment: Try this link for demo.... http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomAdapter.java


 TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button  bt=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);      
        final List<String> arr1;
        final List<String> arr2;
        arr1=(List<String>) Arrays.asList(name);
        arr2=(List<String>) Arrays.asList(no);

        final ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>(arr1);
        final ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>(arr2);


    bt.setOnClickListener(new Listener()); 
        tv1.setText(name[position]);
        tv2.setText(no[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
class Listener implements OnClickListener
{
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        arr.remove(position);
        ar.remove(position);
        a.take().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

}
```

Comment: whats the difference it would made??

Comment: This one of the concept of java reflection because getview is life a loop the no of items in list is the number f times getview is called at that time we need to give different refrences of click listener for individual items.

Answer (score 0):

CustomAdapter

```
public CustomAdapter(Context con, String a[], String b[]) {
    super(con, R.layout.second, a);
    name = a;
    this.con = con;
    no = b;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv1, tv2;
    Button bt;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = new View(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, null);
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.bt = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        convertView.setTag(v);
        final List<String> arr1;
        final List<String> arr2;
        arr1 = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(name);
        arr2 = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(no);

        final ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(arr1);
        final ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>(arr2);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    v.bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            arr.remove(position);
            ar.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    holder.tv1.setText(name[position]);
    holder.tv2.setText(no[position]);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: and http://textuploader.com/y90b for second.xml                                                             But, I don't want to change the xml

Comment: Change your
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.second, null);
to
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.second, parent,false); and button android:focusable="false"

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" . And this attribute has to be added to the top most layout of your XML where you have provided the ListView elements.

Comment: while click just print the toast or log to check its working or not

Comment: can you ping me here koonaharish@gmail.com